# How to keep a div inline-block with an image inside?

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent{
background:silver;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
}

.child{
background:gold;
display:inline-block;
}

.imginside{
display:inline-block;
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
<div class='child'>

<img class='imginside' src='https://static.businessinsider.com/image/50db38a069bedd0d1000000c-750.jpg' alt='img'>

</div>

</div>
```

If a text is inside `child` - it is `inline-block`.

But if an image is inside `child` - `child` becomes `block` (background gold is 100% wide);

How to keep `child - inline-block` with an image inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, with the image inside the child remains `inline-block`. To check, inspect the child element (use devtools on chrome). In the element style it will show `display:inline-block`. What the problem is that you have given `width:50%` to the image. Try using more absolute units like px. I have provided a working example:

```css
.parent{
background:silver;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
}

.child{
background:gold;
display:inline-block;
}

.imginside{
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
<div class='child'>

<img class='imginside' src='https://static.businessinsider.com/image/50db38a069bedd0d1000000c-750.jpg' alt='img'>

</div>

</div>
```

It was working for text as you had not given %width to it.
Hope this clears things out.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to keep the image in its original size, without specifying any width. In this case `child` is 100% wide again. I said `50%` just for an example.

Comment: @blueSky I have editted the code. The image is in its original size.

Comment: @blueSky Increase and decrease the padding to suit your needs. I have mainly focused here that your child element's display doesnt change to block. The styling is easy once you get the concept. Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `width:50%` to the div and make the image `max-width:100%;`

```css
.parent {
  background: silver;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
  background: gold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.imginside {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>

    <img class='imginside' src='https://static.businessinsider.com/image/50db38a069bedd0d1000000c-750.jpg' alt='img'>

  </div>

</div>
```